Создание тг бота для бизнес аккаунта
Хотелось бы узнать какие функции можно реализовать с помощью тг бота, подключенного к бизнес аккаунту. Если вдруг, то вот, о чем я говорю:

Какие вообще библиотеки для этого можно использовать для этого и что интересного сделать. Не нашел как-то об этом информации в интернете, так что решил задать вопрос здесь. Так же буду рад получить статьи или вроде того. Благодарю за внимание!
